# Is there a way to apply :target pseudo-class to aim a certain number of pixels away from a given element?

Tags: css

I'd like to aim navigation links at various points on a single page, and have them land visible below a sticky navigation bar at the top.  I can do something like this:

```
    :target {
      margin-top: 300px;
    }
```

But if the user scrolls back up from the target position, there is an empty gap between the target element and the previous element.  I'd like to avoid that, but I'm having trouble determining how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It may help to include a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate what you want and what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if its kosher to answer my own question, but since there isn't an answer after some time, I thought I'd post what I wound up doing:

I combined the :target, and :before pseudo-classes to get the behavior I wanted.  Worked like a charm:

```
:target:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: -300px;
}
```

Comment: It's okay to do that. Somebody who read the question is happy to find an answer. Can you insert an image of the result somewhere ?